# Why won't psfrag replace string in certain eps files (from MestreNova)?

Tags: eps, psfrag

I am using psfrag to replace string in eps graphics, which works fine with most eps. There are certain eps graphics that won't work with it though, which are mainly graphics exported from MestreNova software. (Some chemistry analytics software)

Minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \psfrag{X}{Benzene}
    \includegraphics[angle=-90,scale=.4]{./1.eps} %angle or scale do not produce the error!
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \psfrag{X}{Benzene}
    \includegraphics{./2.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Whyyy?]

1.eps is from said software (different "X" copied from various sources and written by built-in "text annotation").

2.eps is the usual "chemdraw" eps export, which works fine.

[Download](http://www.mprcrew.de/files/eps_and_result.zip) for eps files.

I am using latex->dvips->gswin64c for generating pdf. (No pdflatex involved!)

Does anyone have a clue what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `psfrag` needs to find the literal text in the `.eps` to replace it. If you search through `1.eps` you won't find a single occurrence of `(X)` (which would be `X` as text). As such there is nothing that can be done by `psfrag`. You'll need to fix this from MestReNova.

Comment: OT for us, but the export by MestReNova might depend on the version you have: which one have you got?